# Can 01 BFS be used to find shortest path in a graph with only 2 weights?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, shortest-path

I have read [this](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/22276) article about 0-1 BFS and I understand it's working for 0-1 weights. However, at the end of the article, the author asked 3 questions, one of which is exactly my question. In the comments, he specified that it doesn't work if the weights are any two numbers x and y.

But why? The logic used still holds. Assuming 0<=x<=y, for any node u, we will only add neighbors that can be relaxed. In addition, all the neighbors that are x away from u will be added to the front of the deque and those that are y away will be added at the back of the deque. This way, the deque will still be sorted based on distance from the current node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In addition, all the neighbors that are x away from u will be added to the front of the deque and those that are y away will be added at the back of the deque. This way, the deque will still be sorted based on distance from the current node.

The deque is not guaranteed to be sorted when x > 0.

Let's say that x=3 and y=5, and we have this graph, and need to find a shortest path from A to E:

```
  A  --3-->  B  --3-->  C

  |                     |
  5                     3
  |                     |
  v                     v

  D   --------3----->   E
```

We start with [A:0] in the queue (the distance from A is 0).

This entry is taken out and we append D:5 and *prepend* B:3, so we have [B:3,D:5]

We take out B:3 and prepend C:6, so we have [C:6,D:5]. This is breaking the sort order, and thus the algorithm is on a wrong footing. It will now expand first on node C instead of node D, and so we find E with a path length of 9, while there is a path of 8.

Only when x=0 you can guarantee that this method will keep the queue sorted.

Comment: Does this mean that 0-1 BFS will work for x=0 and any value y? I understand your example but I still can't understand intuitively why one of the weights has to be 0 and the other can be anything. How can we prove that this will keep the deque sorted (without taking specific examples - prove generally i mean)?

Comment: It will work with any positive value of `y`, but it must be fixed to one constant value. The thing is that in that case any *distance* will be a multiple of `y`. So if you just use another unit of measure, you can map one `y` to 1 (by dividing all distances by `y`), and then you are back to the original 0-1 problem.